# Using arm-eabi-gcc toolchain can't compile the Sox source code

Tags: cross-compiling, sox

I want to add some function provided by sox into my application, which is cross compiled by arm-eabi-gcc toolchain and run in embedded device. So I need the sox library by cross compiling the sox source code. But when I do `./configure` , I encounter a problem, it prints:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I view the `config.log`. Find the reason as below (pick up from config.log):

```
......
/opt/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin//../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
......
```

It can't find c library. I am really confused by it. I have set the environment variable (such as COMPILER, CC, etc.) correctly. And also add the path of toolchain into the $PATH.

Afterwards, I try to compile it with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc and the gcc in PC, it all work correctly. But The project is all based on the arm-eabi, so I can only use it to compile the sox.

Eager for your help. Thanks!